# PHP Regex a Javascript string

Tags: php, javascript, regex, web-scraping

I have just cURL'd a page and am getting a javascript string returned. I would like to preg_match it so I can use the numbers in a PHP script. I am horrible at regex and have been trying all sorts of things for the last few hours to get it to work. I would appreciate any information you can send my way.

```
document.getElementById('vars').href = "/x/69402770/"+(592630%51245 + 592630%913)+" /";
```

Is the line that I'm getting via the cURL. I'd like to just get all the numbers into an array.
69402770, 592630, 51245, 592630, and 913.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression below should yield an array with the 4 numbers

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $yourJSString, $res);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Hmm. I could sworn I tried that. Which I just did again. I do print_r($matches) and only get : Array
(
    [0] => 69402770
    [1] => 69402770
)

Comment: I just got these results:  Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 69402770 [1] => 592630 [2] => 51245 [3] => 592630 [4] => 913 ) )

Comment: be sure to use preg_match_all

Comment: does it matter that there's a % in the ( 592630%51245 + 592630%913 ) statement?

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm still a total programming newbie, hence the silly mistakes ;)

Comment: what if I wanted to get the text at the end of the same string : document.getElementById('vars').href = "/x/69402770/"+(592630%51245 + 592630%913)+"/2011-text-here.html";

Comment: nvm I just used /"\/([^"]+)"/